# Curved Path2D becomes straight when increasing stroke size

Tags: path, java-2d, stroke

I have this strange problem with Java2D. I have a `Path2D.Double` that I want to draw, but depending on the stroke size, all segments are drawn correctly (curved) but when the stroke size is greater or equal than 0.00005d the segments are drawn straight. As you can see, the only parameter I'm changing is the stroke size. What am I doing wrong?

```
BasicStroke basicStroke1 = new BasicStroke(.00004f, CAP_ROUND, JOIN_ROUND);
g2draw.setStroke(basicStroke1);
g2draw.draw(path);

BasicStroke basicStroke2 = new BasicStroke(.00006f, CAP_ROUND, JOIN_ROUND);
g2draw.setStroke(basicStroke2);
g2draw.draw(path);
```

And here a picture with the result of this code:

[image]

Comment: What kind of `shape` you are trying to draw ? it is better if u can provide your `shape` code as well

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error seems to be rounding errors when transforming user coordinates to screen coordinates, when the scale difference is big (or not so big...). It's an odd behaviour of Java2D. Switched to JavaFX and the problem disappeared.